# How to add image & title to Podcast Feed dynamically

Tags: views, feeds

Using either View - RSS Fields / iTunes - (https://www.drupal.org/node/1473728) or [FFPC](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffpc) module

I have a content type for a Podcast and a second content type for Episodes.  Episodes are related to the Podcast which has the Title & Art (images) associated with it.

The feed is mydomain.com/podcast/feed/[nodeid]

On our website, this "subscribe" link is auto-generated for clicking while viewing the Podcast node.  We're utilizing a contextual filter for the feed to populate properly.

The feed works from a technical point of view.  However, neither [FFPC](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffpc) nor [iTunes](https://www.drupal.org/project/itunes) module appear to allow me to set the Title or Images dynamically.

Has anyone set something similar up where the Title, Image and potentially other fields are set dynamically during the feed generation rather than in a config panel Administratively.

Adding:
Content-Type Podcast
Title = Fred's Podcast
podcastImage = fres-square-image.jpg

Content-Type Podcast Episode
Title = Learning Drupal
mp3File = learning.mp3

Content-Type Podcast Episode
Title = RSS Feeds
mp3File = rssfeeds.mp3

View - Podcast Feeds
  Filter - Published & type-PodcastEpisode
  Contextual filter - Podcast Nid , using relationship Podcast
  Relationships - Entity Relationship, Podcast (identifier) - Referencing entity

The view/feed shows all Podcast Episodes for parent podcast based on NID.  The feed works fine, but I need to set the TITLE and IMAGE for the podcast to be the IMAGE and TITLE from the parent (NID) node content.  No problem if this is php code, just don't know where/how to inject.

Comment: `set the Title or Images dynamically` can you elaborate more on that? give an example.

Comment: updated original question for formatting